# Django add to watchlist No Jquery

Tags: django

I was having a struggle to get the Add to Watchlist sorted out and the method below illustrate how i achieve that without utilization of Jquery in my codes and keep it simple Django/Python.

Models:

```
class Startup ( models.Model ) :
    author = models.OneToOneField ( User , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    startup_name = models.CharField ( max_length = 32 , null = False , blank = False )
    wl = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'watchlist', blank = True)


    def __str__(self) :
        return str ( self.startup_name )
```

View for Global_list (listing) and watchlist function:

```
@login_required
@inv_required
def global_list(request):
    startup = Startup.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'inv_template/global_list.html', {'startup': startup})

@login_required
@inv_required
def watchlist (request, id):
    check = Startup.objects.get(id=id)
    if check.wl.exists():
        check.wl.remove(request.user)
        check.save()
    else:
        check.wl.add(request.user)
        check.save()
    return redirect ( 'globallist' )
```

Global list that contain the watch list link:

```
{% extends 'inv_template/inv_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% include 'inv_template/inv_nav.html' %}
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px; font-size: 14px;background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);">
    {% for s in startup.all %}
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
        <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="card-body shadow">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-end align-items-lg-center"><a href="{% url 'watchlist' s.id %}">
                        <i class="far fa-eye"></i><i class="fas fa-plus" style="font-size: 7px;"></i>
                    </a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 text-center d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center align-items-lg-center"><a href="{% url 'applicationdetail' s.id %}" type="submit" style="font-size: 29px;">{{s.startup_name}}</a></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <div class="row">
                            {% for g in s.generalinformation_set.all %}
                            <div class="col-lg-3"><label class="col-form-label" style="color: rgba(0,27,252,0.85);font-size: 12px;"><strong>Established</strong>:</label><br/>{{g.established}}</div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3"><label class="col-form-label" style="color: rgba(0,27,252,0.85);font-size: 12px;"><strong>Stage:</strong></label><br/>{{g.stage}}</div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3"><label class="col-form-label" style="color: rgba(0,27,252,0.85);font-size: 12px;"><strong>Type:</strong></label><br/>{{g.type}}</div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3"><label class="col-form-label" style="color: rgba(0,27,252,0.85);font-size: 12px;"><strong>Location:</strong></label><br/>{{g.location.name}}</div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12"><label class="col-form-label" style="color: rgba(0,27,252,0.85);font-size: 12px;"><strong>Business Stage:</strong></label> {{g.stage_select}}</div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center align-items-lg-center"><label class="col-form-label" style="padding-left: 0px;font-size: 8px;">(<strong>0 </strong>Views)</label></div>
                    {% for f in s.fund_set.all %}
                    <div class="col"><label class="col-form-label" style="color: rgba(0,27,252,0.85);font-size: 12px;"><strong>Requested Fund:</strong></label> {{f.req_amount}}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div style="">
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

URLS:

```
    # Global List Router
    path ( 'globallist/' , views.global_list , name = 'globallist' ) ,

    # Watchlist Router
    path ( 'watchlist/<int:pk>' , views.watchlist , name = 'watchlist' ) ,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Above codes are the updated ones that illustrate the method of add to watchlist without Jquery.